# PySpark's DataFrame.show() runs slow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Newbie here, I read a table(about 2 million rows) as Spark's DataFrame via JDBC from MySQL in PySpark and trying to show the top 10 rows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName("test_log_processing").getOrCreate()
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
table = "test.fakelog"
properties = {"user": "myUser", "password": "********"}
df = spark_session.read.jdbc(url, table, properties=properties)
df.cache()
df.show(10)  # can't get the printed results, and runs pretty slow and consumes 90%+ CPU resources
spark_session.stop()
```

And here's the console log:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]
```

My education background is statistics and recently just started to learn Spark so I've no idea what's going on behind the code(for smallere dataset, this works well), how should I fix this problem? Or what more knowledge should I know about Spark?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- Maybe your cache to memory is getting filled up, the default for cache used to be memory only(older spark versions).
- Therefore, Instead of cache can you try df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK). It will spill to disk when memory gets too full.
- Try .take(10), it will give a collection of rows, it might not be faster but its worth a try
- Try df.coalesce(50).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK), works well without a shuffle if you have an over-partitioned dataframe
- If none of these work it probably means your computing cluster is incapable of handling this load, you might need to scale out.

Comment: df.coalesce(50).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) works well, it seems that it's actually caused by shuffling and partitioning.

Comment: seeing as your dataframe as not too big (at 2million rows), its possible that it was overpartitioned, the coalesce reduces those partitions so that the data is more efficiently distributed and it prevents a shuffle while doing that. win win for this case

Answer (score 1):

Since you call the `spark.read.jdbc` for some table, the spark will try to collect the whole table from the database into the spark. After that, spark cache the data and print 10 result from the cache. If you run the below code, you will notice some differences.

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName("test_log_processing").getOrCreate()
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"
table = "(SELECT * FROM test.fakelog LIMIT 10) temp"
properties = {"user": "myUser", "password": "********"}
df = spark_session.read.jdbc(url, table, properties=properties)
df.cache()
df.show()
spark_session.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've got the print but I actually need the whole table for other usage